# Motion Tween with multiple scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

New to Flash and AS3.
 I have a flash AS3 app I am making. It has multiple scenes and the user starts at scene one, and then follows a menu on the left to navigate to the other scenes. 
  I need to add a motion tween to the front page only.

In my actionscript, I have to have "stop()" because if I don't the multiple scenes won't work effectively. However because of this, the motion tween never is able to start. How do I make it so the app runs, and the first screen stays up, but it starts with a motion tween?

I hope I explained myself well.

Answer (score 0):

Move the stop() to the last frame of your tween.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but what you're trying to achieve can be done by embedding movie clips, you can insert a movie clip inside another movie clip, inside first frame, you can issue a stop() but at the same time, create a movie clip of whatever the first frame has and under that movie clip, do not insert any script.
The structure goes like this:

```
     // Main MovieClip
   _______|________________________
   |                 |   |   |    |
   F1(stop() here)   F2 F3  F4    F4  (frames)
   |
   |
// Menu MovieClip
   |
   |________________
   |    |    |     |
   F1   F2   F3   F4
```

Also make sure your navigation is working(gotoAndPlay())

Answer (score 0):

In AS2

If you are using the tween class to move an object you could do

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

this.onLoad = function():Void
{
     var tween1:Tween = new Tween(....
}
```

if your tween is part of a frame by frame animation put the stop() on the last frame before changing scene.